# Is com.sun.javafx.robot.FXRobot proprietary

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to javafx, and I recently came across the FXRobot class. It works fine, but I am concerned about the long term support of the class, because usually when I use a com.sun class, the javac gives this error message:

> warning: com.sun.* is an internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

Although the FXRobot class does not give me the above error, I just wanted to ask if the FXRobot class is a permanent part of the JDK, and if it is, then why is it not bundled with the javafx package instead of the com.sun.javafx package.

Comment: As all the `com.sun.*` packages are intended used internally only, they can be removed anytime, as they are not part of the public contract. Normally you should not use it for any productive code. Anyways robots can be mainly used for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried java 9, but I think there is a very good chance that `com.sun.javafx.robot.FXRobot` would not be usable from Java 9 user code due to the introduction of the Jigsaw module system and the systematic hiding of non-public API which goes along with that.

See: [JEP 253: Prepare JavaFX UI Controls & CSS APIs for Modularization](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8076423), which translates a lot of API which is private in Java 8 to public in Java 9, but which does not include the FXRobot class in the translation.

Also see this mailing list exchange, which mentions removal of the `com.sun.javafx.robot` package from the Java 9 codebase:

- http://openjfx-dev.openjdk.java.narkive.com/ZR9JPyC4/removal-of-com-sun-javafx-robot

So, it would seem not to be a good idea to rely on the FXRobot class.